# git: use "commit --cleanup=whitespace" with "rebase --interactive"

Tags: git

I want to *always* use `--cleanup=whitespace` when creating/editing commit messages (to allow for initial "#"). Unfortunately, I can't find a proper setting to put in `~/.gitconfig`; this one doesn't work:

```
[commit]
    cleanup = whitespace
```

For normal commits I added `--cleanup=whitespace` to my main commit alias, but
I can't figure out how to pass this option to `git rebase --interactive` so that I could reword and squash commits and use my preferred cleanup method.

Comment: I have no idea either, and I need it too, so just +1

Comment: Could you please be more specific

Comment: The new `git commit --cleanup=scissors` mode could be of interest here. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22653672/6309)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [git 1.8.2](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt) they added the setting I was trying to use:

> "git commit" can be told to use --cleanup=whitespace by setting the
>   configuration variable commit.cleanup to 'whitespace'.

Meanwhile, I just started adding a single space before a `#`...

Comment: Also, setting `commentChar = ";"` under `[core]` within `.gitconfig` is useful for writing Markdown-formatted commit messages that contain headings that start with `#`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corecommentChar

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file `.git/config` in your projtect's folder.
2. In the file, you will find a `[core]` section. E.g., for me it looks like this:

   ```
   [core]
       repositoryformatversion = 0
       filemode = false
       bare = false
       logallrefupdates = true
       symlinks = false
       ignorecase = true
   ```

   Add `commentChar = ";"` to the end of this section (or choose another character than `;` if you have another preference). You can read more about this setting here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corecommentChar. In my case, the section now looks like this:

   ```
   [core]
       repositoryformatversion = 0
       filemode = false
       bare = false
       logallrefupdates = true
       symlinks = false
       ignorecase = true
       commentChar = ";"
   ```
3. Now, do the rebase. E.g.:

   ```
   $ git rebase -i HEAD~4
   ```
4. In my case, I choose to reword my commits:

   ```
   r ca9bb66 #77204 Change formatting in ActiveFundOrderSubstateHandler.cs
   r 7879f86 #77204 Rename class
   r ff1adc3 #77204 Formatting change
   r 9df6615 #77294 Fix formatting
   ```
5. And now, I'm able to change my commit messages while keeping `#` in the beginning of them.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
[alias]
    rec = rebase --interactive
```